# j2me netbeans - parallel data transfer (outline idea required)

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I am new to j2me Mobile Applications. I have a college project to be done within a month. I need some basic idea of how it can be done. I am using Netbeans 6.8 j2me platform.
I have to create source, destination and many intermediate nodes(mobile phones). A file has to be sent(am using Bluetooth) from source to destination via several intermediate nodes. The file can be split into chunks and can also be sub-divided at any level.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/parallelism.jpg/

This is how it should work:

1. Initially, the source sends simple objects of a Class(present in all nodes) to destination via several paths. Every node will be updating the object by including its Bluetooth address and passes it to the next node. When it reaches the destination, the same object is sent back to the source. The source identifies some of the optimal paths and uses them for file transfer.
2. The source splits the file and send them to the nearest nodes. The intermediate nodes can also split and send the  divided parts.
3. When all the parts reach the destination, they are joined and the file is reconstructed.

   I created separate netbeans project for source, destination and intermediate node. 
   Splitting : I did splitting successfully by converting the file into byte array and creating files using File connection & outputstream

   ```
   public void splitfiles(int len)
     {
   String url="file:///root1/testfile.jpg";
   // int len = 102400;
   byte buffer[] = new byte[size];
   int count = 0;

    try
       {
   FileConnection fconi = (FileConnection)Connector.open(url,Connector.READ);
   InputStream fis = fconi.openInputStream();

        while (true)
        {
         int i = fis.read(buffer, 0, len);  //creating byte array of size "len" bytes
         if (i == -1)
            break;
         ++count;

     String filename ="file:///root1/testfile.part" + count;
     FileConnection fcono = (FileConnection)Connector.open(filename,Connector.READ_WRITE);
     if (!fcono.exists())
           fcono.create();
     OutputStream fos = fcono.openOutputStream();

     fos.write(buffer, 0, i);  //creating files out of byte array "buffer"
     fos.close();
     fcono.close();
   }  

   }
   catch(Exception e)
           {        }
   }
   ```

Please tell me how to rejoin the files.(I rejoined them using java class  "RandomAcessFile" which is not present in j2me).
I tried in the following way

```
while(number of chunks)
{
read a single file in inputstream (files are read one after the other)
copy it to a byte array and flush inputstream
write it to ouputstream
}
copy outputstream to a file
flush outputstream
```

Please give me some idea about

1. how to rejoin the chunks in j2me
2. How to pass object of a class via bluetooth